# Google Cookie decode

Tags: google-app-engine

I develop something that base on Google service.

Now i noticed that they add a sessionid to their services and now i need to find it too.

I make a lot of searches and i noticed that they save a cookie with a name : "`SID`", so i think that it is.

```
Set-Cookie: SID=DQAAALgAAABk20DNISbQnTIm0DHuZIhhJyMg3Gs9i1gxXZrlzfc66Fq05cxvpHShc1pcFzcW0bnFLcROwZSgoiECL2J-_tJ8iGkKh25GYutor0HD15DFjMO_HeUoG4MmrKR3WO8ShxWP624YY_l_sFES6RJzhUHQtvUk0AGtscU7XodCqDjL_7XZXhCsJlBEjB09PYxyxlbEx76ebiMYop-vIx47sTmV-ygoqFaxUfmAnRja9mMbNAu8c_XbQ8Gr9UM0QuviKsE;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 07-Apr-2022 09:48:05 GMT
```

My question is if their is a way yo decode what wrote in the cookie value to a number(because the session id is a number)

Comment: It could be a key, not a Int Number... And also, it could encrypted.

Comment: What session ID are you referring to? And why do you care what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most sites set a cookie by generating a random string of letters, associating it with the user (in a secret server-side database), and using it to look up the user whenever the cookie is given back to the site. There is literally no information in the cookie itself -- it is just an arbitrary string that only means something to the server. So there's nothing to "decode". It's just random noise.

I don't know any details about Google's cookies in particular, but I assume they follow standard practice, which means the above should be true.